# Проблема с передачей строки в другую функцию с++

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++

Данная часть программы проверяет является ли числом введенная из файла строка. При попытке передать строку в функцию str_or_int выходит 4 ошибки:

Ошибка  C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "string"   Mn.h    23
Ошибка  C2511   int Input::str_or_int(std::string): перегруженная функция-член не найдена в "Input" Mn.cpp  25
Ошибка  C2660   Input::str_or_int: функция не принимает 1 аргументов    Mn.cpp  91
Ошибка  C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "string"   Mn.h    23

Mn.h

```
#pragma once


class Input
{

int num,v;


public:
struct Xy
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Xy* k;
Xy* k2;

int n, n2;

Input();
int str_or_int(string str);
void set_k();
//~Input();

};
```

Mn.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Mn.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>





using namespace std;

Input::Input() {
n = 0;
n2 = 0;
num = 0;
v = 0;
k = { 0 };
k2 = { 0 };

}

int Input::str_or_int(string str)
{
//char str[256], * p = str;
bool flag = true;
int len,number;
char* s;
int i = 0;
len = str.length(); // находим длину введённой строки
s = new char[str.length() + 1]; // создаём символьный массив, равной длине введённой строки
strcpy_s(s, str.length() + 1, str.c_str()); // переводим строку в символьный массив


while (s[i]) 
{
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char)s[i]))
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
if (flag)
{
    number = atoi(s);
    return (number);
}
else
{
    cout << "ОШИБКА! Вы ввели не число" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
}

void Input::set_k()
{
ifstream file;
file.open("qwerty.txt");
if (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Ошибка при открытии файла!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Файл успешно открыт" << endl;

    string st;
    file >> st;
    n = str_or_int(st);
```

Comment: Добавьте `#include <string>` в файле Mn.h. И затем, либо добавьте `using namespace std`, либо замените `string`  на `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс строки в стандартной библиотеке языка С++ называется `std::string`. `string` и `std::string` - это не одно и то же. Именно об этом вам и говорит компилятор. В строке 23 файла `Mn.h` он не знает никакого `string`.